# Custom appender in logback configuration with Spring extension not working

Tags: spring, logback, appender

My ultimate goal is to use my custom appender in a Spring boot app. The appender needs to autowired other variable which is not working if I referenced the appender directly in the logback.xml. I found reading about logback extension for spring https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions/wiki/Spring . I tried to following the directions, but the custom appender was not instantiated. The log shows that the DelegatingLogbackAppender was indeed created, but I don't know why it is not linked with my appender.

Here is my logback.xml:

```
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="rabbitmqAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.DelegatingLogbackAppender"/> 
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="rabbitmqAppender"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Here is my Spring configuration code (less import lines):

```
@Configuration
public class LogbackConfig 
{
    @Bean 
    public static ApplicationContextHolder applicationContextHolder() {
        return new ApplicationContextHolder ();
    }

    @Bean 
    public static LoggerContext loggerContext() {
        return (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    }

    @Bean (initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public static PatternLayoutEncoder encoder (LoggerContext ctx) {
        PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
        encoder.setContext(ctx);
        encoder.setPattern("%date %-5level [%thread] %logger{36} %m%n");
        return encoder;
    }

    @Bean (initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public static RabbitMQAppender rabbitmqAppender(LoggerContext ctx, PatternLayoutEncoder encoder) {
        RabbitMQAppender appender = new RabbitMQAppender();
        appender.setContext(ctx);
        return appender;
    }
}
```

I also tried to use the ConsoleAppender shown in the doc example. It didn't show any log lines in the console either.

Comment: I suspect the Configuration class was never ran for some reason. This class is packaged with the appender class in a jar, and then the jar is packaged in a spring boot app. Do I need to do anything else other than marking the class as @Configuration?

Comment: Like I mentioned earlier that my goal was to make @Autowired work in my appender. It was not working if I define my custom appeneder directly in logback.xml. So I thought I need to use the logback spring extension so the Autowired would work in my appender. If there is another way to make this work, I will be happy to hear that too. Thanks!

Comment: How do you load that LogbackConfig class? It's working as expected with my tests.